# Will Skype be removed from the Canonical Partner repository?

Tags: skype, canonical, official-repositories, license

I just learned that [Microsoft has taken over Skype](http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/business-13343600).

Will this affect the availability of Skype in the Canonical Partner repository?

Comment: If that happen don't worry The GNU Project has announced a new project called GNU Free Call, an open source Skype alternative http://planet.gnu.org/gnutelephony/?p=14  don't you think this is for a purpose ;)

Comment: @Achu: Really? GNU Free Call would be great! :) Now we just need a GNU Flash :P

Comment: @Daniel0108: actually, there are already open-source Flash players, but these cannot run all flash files yet.

Comment: @Achu That is a nice sounding ideal, but I would venture that most of us who don't already use obscure, open-source alternatives to the near universally-adopted existing solutions are not likely to be in a position to ask our correspondents to switch away from what is already familiar, already the norm, and already meets their needs.

Comment: This is a bit quick to be worried about this. Skype is still its own company until the transaction goes through, and Canonical may keep the partnership with the Skype division. Also, Canonical may be contractually obligated to keep Skype in the partner repository for a certain number of years.

Comment: @ændrük first time yes, you are right. you can see ubuntu's experience, everybody was using windows now you can how many people use ubuntu \o/ :)

Comment: @Achu: GNU Free Call.... SERIOUSLY? If Hurd is any example - this is a joke. What we need is something along the lines of LibreOffice (in terms of community, momentum, and dedication).

Comment: I see there is a vote that this is "not a real question." I try not to make this error. Would the individual making this claim please explain what he or she feels I did wrong?

Comment: Try Google GTalk... Btw. if you have a googlemail account you automatically have a gtalk account. Its jabber and workes like a charm with voice/video...

Comment: @aendruk I voted not a real question since any answer will be totally speculative.

Comment: @JorgeCastro: except the ones that provide references...

Answer (score 7):

According what I [read](http://www.osnews.com/story/24718/Microsoft_To_Acquire_Skype_for_8_5_Billion), MS will still support Skype for non-Microsoft platforms. Skype not only runs on desktop OSes, but also on mobile OSes such as Android. So it would really be short-sighted of MS to stop supporting it on non-Microsoft platforms.

Comment: Agrred... buy I'd say MS has been short-sighted at times before :). Hope they aren't with Skype.

Comment: Furthermore, killing Skype for non-MS platforms reduces the value of Skype for users on MS platforms, since they can call less people.

Comment: Note this [response](https://twitter.com/#!/ActionLamb/status/81062856564543489) from the 'Microsoft Open Source Strategist' Steve Lamb: "It's too early to know plans re. Skype - the deal has to close before we can do anything"

Answer (score 0):

Depends how partner'ish will it be with Canonical. If it belongs to Microsoft, it doesn't necessarily mean that it will cancel its previous partnerships.

Comment: Does that mean Microsoft assumes the contract... and that Canonical will be a partner with Microsoft...?!?

Comment: it's not the contract rather than being aware and tolerant to other platforms