# Will Skype support for Ubuntu be removed?

Tags: skype

I was curious (and concerned). Since Microsoft has completely taken over Skype, does it mean, they will stop supporting Skype for Ubuntu?

Comment: While not 150% a duplicate, your question is mostly answered here. http://askubuntu.com/questions/41802/will-skype-be-removed-from-the-canonical-partner-repository - basically, it comes down to "we don't know"